# Calculate employee shift based on 1st login of the day

Tags: sql, case

I want to calculate employees shift based on his system login time ,i am able to calculate shifts based on login times .now i want to calculate shift only for 1st login entry for given day if there are multiple logins for same day.Please help how i can do this .

**

SQL Query :

```
WITH shiftalloence AS
(
       SELECT (timesheet.start_time_server) ,
              users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name AS employee_name ,
              CASE
                     WHEN Dateadd(d, -Datediff(d, 0, dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server), dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server) BETWEEN '05:30:00' AND    '08:00:00' THEN 'Morning'
                     WHEN Dateadd(d, -Datediff(d, 0, dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server), dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server) BETWEEN '08:01:00' AND    '11:00:00' THEN 'General'
                     WHEN Dateadd(d, -Datediff(d, 0, dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server), dbo.[timesheet].start_time_server) BETWEEN '11:05:00' AND    '18:00:00' THEN 'Evening'
                     ELSE '0'
              END AS shift
       FROM   timesheet
       JOIN   users
       ON     timesheet.user_id=users.user_id
       WHERE  Month(start_time_server)=Month(Getdate())
       AND    Datename(weekday,timesheet.start_time_server) IN 'Monday',
              'Tuesday',
              'Wednesday',
              'Thursday',
              'Friday')
AND
start_time_server NOT IN
(
       SELECT timesheet.start_time_server
       FROM   timesheet
       JOIN   leaves
       ON     timesheet.user_id=leaves.user_id
       WHERE  CONVERT(varchar(10),timesheet.start_time_server,111) =CONVERT(varchar(10),leaves.start_time_server,111)
       AND    task_type_name IN ('leave',
                                 'Half Day') )), tt AS
(
         SELECT   shiftalloence.employee_name ,
                  count(
                  CASE
                           WHEN shift = 'Morning' THEN 1
                           ELSE NULL
                  END) AS 'Morning',
                  count(
                  CASE
                           WHEN shift = 'General' THEN 1
                           ELSE NULL
                  END) AS 'General' ,
                  count(
                  CASE
                           WHEN shift = 'Evening' THEN 1
                           ELSE NULL
                  END) AS 'Evening'
         FROM     shiftalloence
         GROUP BY employee_name )SELECT *
FROM   tt
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Could you just simply distinct select and order by ASC or DESC depending on the dates? This would allow you to show just the shift/day/id you're wanting and showing you the first time they logged in because you're ordered it in the way you're wanting.

This works because if you get back 3 rows and order by the datetime asc/desc you can also simply do select top(1). It'll grab just the top record in that list for that shift/day/person.

Small example of what I am saying:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees
order by datetime asc;
```

Something like that.

Comment: one more question if i go with top 1 as you shared ,how i can apply this for user 1 . Suppose User 1 did login  for 4 (6am,2pm,7 pm and 11 pm)times in a day so .I should have his 1st login entry i.e.6am for the day and  mark 1st shift as for him and rest 3 entries for user 1 will be skip

Comment: You would simply make sure you do the orderby. Something like SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees where User = User1 order by datetime asc